# How do I save the google image map API picture to my server

Tags: php, google-maps

Is it possible to save the google map image API as an image to my server?

**Background:** Google map image API is generating an image of the desired location. Every time I am calling for the external URL. Can I save the map image as an image(png, gif) on my server? This will improve my web page speed. I tried with curl but failed to copy the image

Requested  url 
[http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=15719+OAKLEAF+RUN+DRIVE%2CLITHIA%2CFL%2C33547%2CUS&zoom=8&size=150x100&markers=color:blue|label:S|11211&sensor=false](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=15719%20OAKLEAF%20RUN%20DRIVE,LITHIA,FL,33547,US&zoom=8&size=150x100&markers=color:blue%7Clabel:S%7C11211&sensor=false)

Comment: Please make sure to read the terms of service, as what you're describing may well violate them.

Comment: @Mano Marks Yes. We can request max of 1000 queries per user

Comment: I'm more concerned with you saving them to your server

Answer (score 18, accepted):

you can try something like this:

```
<?php
$image = file_get_contents('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=15719%20OAKLEAF%20RUN%20DRIVE,LITHIA,FL,33547,US&zoom=8&size=150x100&markers=color%3ablue%7Clabel%3aS%7C11211&sensor=false'); 
$fp  = fopen('ae.png', 'w+'); 

fputs($fp, $image); 
fclose($fp); 
unset($image);
?>
```

Comment: Is this answer still valid with the current API? I am trying to base64 encode the image from the Staticmaps API and file_get_contents(<api url>) always returns false.

Comment: As of Feb 2023 this is still valid. It worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

you can easily read that url using file_get_contents

snippet for this will be

```
$url='http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=15719+OAKLEAF+RUN+DRIVE%2CLITHIA%2CFL%2C33547%2CUS&zoom=8&size=150x100&markers=color:blue|label:S|11211&sensor=false';

file_put_contents('filename.png',file_get_contents($url));
```

Answer (score 2):

This is really easy

just use

```
if(@copy('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=15719%20OAKLEAF%20RUN%20DRIVE,LITHIA,FL,33547,US&zoom=8&size=150x100&markers=color%3ablue%7Clabel%3aS%7C11211&sensor=false', '/where-u-want-to-save/your-given-name.png')){
echo "image-saved";
}else{
echo "failed"; }
```

> image always returns as png format
>   you may give image a unique name by lat lng value or using php time() function

Comment: &zoom=13&size=500x400&maptype=hybrid&markers=color:red&sensor=false&format=jpg-baseline how to also print the markers?

Comment: @dstonek since API changed a lot, check https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/icon-simple

Comment: I fixed that adding a custom mark using ImageMagick. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Check the Maps API for mobile.  There you will receive an Image instead of a HTML map.