# Switch between google maps and google earth

Tags: asp.net, google-maps, c#-4.0, kml, google-earth

Using a KML file I can show Google Earth  in website. Now, can anyone give me idea to implement following specification?

- I need following buttons above the Google Earth plugin
- a. User must be able to switch between map and earth.
- b. User should be able to save and download the map or earth as image

So we have to use same KML file (that is used for google earth) to show google map. After that google earth or the google maps have to be saved as image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per i know,same kml will not work for google maps and google earth.Becuase, Google Earth kml is some what different to Google Maps kml.In Google Earth kml we need to declare `<LookAt>` that is not supported by Google Maps.Please have a look into the following url for Google Earth kml:

```
http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/kml_tut.html
```

and the following url explains google maps kml:

```
http://econym.org.uk/gmap/kml.htm
```

Here we have to observe one more thing like we have `<coordinates>` in both cases.But ,the Projection is different in both cases.If we use same `lat` and `lon` for Google Earth and Google Maps we cannot able to get the correct result.So,you can use both kml but while passing coordinates from Google maps to Google earth,need to change the lat,lon projections and vice versa.

Hope this helps you :-)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation :-)  what about 'user should be able to save and download the map or earth as image'? have any idea?

Comment: Please look into this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9358684/how-do-i-save-the-google-image-map-api-picture-to-my-server  In this url php is used.you can use .net to get the image.But you need to pass the url as mentioned in this link

Comment: Yes, this is to save google map as image but if we can have a way to save google earth as image too

Comment: Hope we cannot save images from google earth plugin.Please refer this :http://code.google.com/p/earth-api-samples/issues/detail?id=87