# Google Static Map Authorisation with Key not working

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-static-api

I have the following Google Developer Console APIs with ON status:

- Google Maps Embed API
- Google Maps Javascript API v3
- Static Maps API
- BigQuery AP
- Google Cloud SQL
- Google Cloud Storage
- Google Cloud Storage JSON API

I have the following link in an HTML email:

> ```
> <img src='http://maps.google.com/staticmap?center=-15,-47&zoom=11&size=600x200&key=myKey'/>
> ```

But I never get an image.  The key works OK for an embedded map using an iframe.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Google static Map API, you should use this URL:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=-15,-47&zoom=11&size=600x200&key=myKey
```

Of course, replace 'myKey' to your valid key.

Answer (score 0):

It won't work because you're trying to put it in an email, browsers work differently to email clients. Email clients block iframes for security purposes, see:

[Is there no way to embed a Google Map into an HTML email?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24355007/is-there-no-way-to-embed-a-google-map-into-an-html-email)

You can check if your api key is working using the Google Maps API console https://code.google.com/apis/console/?pli=1

**Update**

also you might want to update the bit of the string 'myKey' with your api key :)

Comment: 1. I have seen this work in HTML emails from ABNB using the same format.

Comment: 2. I am not using an iframe in the HTML email.  You can see in the snippet I  have an <img> tag with the src pointing to google static map.

Comment: 3. I know the key is working because I am using it within an iframe on my website.

Comment: 4. Of course I am replacing myKey with my actual key!