# Showing Google Maps in email

Tags: php, yii, yii1.x

I have the following code in my email template:

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3022.6173606180814!2d-73.98784413488774!3d40.74844444332261!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x89c259a9aeb1c6b5%3A0x35b1cfbc89a6097f!2sEmpire+State+Building%2C+350+5th+Ave%2C+New+York%2C+NY+10118!5e0!3m2!1sen!2s!4v1488865918048" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I used yiiMailer in order to send mails to the users, and I have the following code in my controller:

```
$topic='Message';
$letter = $this->renderPartial('application.views.mail.email_temp',array('model'=>$model, 'topic'=>$topic, ''),true);
$message=$letter;
$mail = new YiiMailer('contact',array('message'=>$message));
$mail->setSubject('Message');
```

But, when I open the sent email, it is not showing Google Maps (tested with Gmail). How can I show Google Maps in my email?

Comment: This has been asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24355007/is-there-no-way-to-embed-a-google-map-into-an-html-email
Also in case you haven't add $mail->IsHtml(true); to enable html email.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get JavaScript maps working in email, and Gmail won't let you embed an iframe to an email. **(iFrames and JavaScript added to an email in this way would be considered a security risk.)**

What you **can** do, however, is embed a static map image on your email.

1. Go to http://staticmapmaker.com/google/ and enter location wanted.
2. Copy the generated static map image and paste it the email.
3. Copy the href from the *"Map with link to Google
   Maps"* section.
4. Select the image you copied/pasted into your email and do command/ctrl+k to add a link to that image.
5. Paste the url from step #3 into Web Address field.