# How to send iframe via Django email?

Tags: django, django-email

I have a HTML template of my e-mail message with embded google map, via iframe.
How can I send email with iframe integration in django?

Comment: You can't generally embed a map into emails, email clients don't like it. The best thing to do is to use a static map: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24355007/is-there-no-way-to-embed-a-google-map-into-an-html-email

Comment: Thank you!
I also know that they don't like it and used static map, but wanted to know if it is possible. Thanx