# Access VBA code to extract google map result from AA mileage calculator website

Tags: html, vba, ms-access, web

I am trying to use vba (Access 2013) to automate a route finder website (https://www.theaa.com/driving/mileage-calculator.jsp)

I have some working code that on a form command button allows me to:
1. open an external instance of internet explorer (as opposed to a browser control)
2. enter postcode/address information from my db
3. click a link that adds further destination fields if required
4. change cost per mile default from a text box on my form
5. click a button called "Get Route"

When "Get Route" is clicked this produces a page with the results of the search, which include a static google map with the route steps marked on a purple line A B C etc. I want to capture this image and use in my db form using a webbrowser or image field control so I can use it in a report when I have conducted searches for the most economical route.

I have looked at the DOM Explorer and source code but I can't work out how to do this or if it is possible? There is a div "gmnoprint" that is highlighted when the map is selected and in the source code there is a reference to "mapContainer" which seems to be in the right area of the sequence of actions/results.

I don't know how to drill through the references and create code which will allow me to put the map in my form. The selection of code I have posted is one part of a select case which determines what can be entered into my text boxes, the GoogleMap image code would presumably go where indicated?

I would say I am an enthusistic learner and a moderate user without any formal training. I would very much appreciate any replies.

```
Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
Dim doc As HTMLDocument
Dim RDate As String
On Error GoTo Errorhandler

RDate = Me.TxtRouteDate
'................................................................

Select Case Me.TxtNoSum
    Case Is = IsNull(Me.TxtPC1) Or IsNull(Me.TxtPC2)
        MsgBox "Please Enter at least 2 Postcodes"
    Case Is <= 2
        MsgBox "Please Enter at least 2 Postcodes"
    Case Is = 3
        IE.Visible = True
        IE.Navigate "https://www.theaa.com/driving/mileage-calculator.jsp"
        IE.Top = 20
        IE.Left = 50
        IE.Height = 1300
        IE.Width = CInt(Int((1000 * Rnd()) + 1))
        While IE.Busy
            DoEvents
        Wend
        Set doc = IE.Document
        With doc
            'Clears previous searches
            doc.all("mcDeleteRoutesLink").Click
            'Inserts info into web site text boxes.
            doc.getElementById("RouteDate").Value = RDate
            doc.getElementById("RouteFrom").Value = Me.TxtPC1
            doc.getElementById("RouteTo").Value = Me.TxtPC2
            doc.getElementById("fuelPricePerLitre").Value = Me.TxtPPL
        End With
        While IE.Busy
            DoEvents
        Wend
        'Clicks "Get Route" Button
        Dim btn As Object
        Set btn = doc.getElementById("getRouteWrapper").Children(0)
        If Not btn Is Nothing Then
            btn.Click
            While IE.Busy
                DoEvents
            Wend
            ' Inserts distance recorded by AA mileage calculator into text control on my form
            Set htmlDist = doc.all("routeDistanceTotal")
            If Not htmlDist Is Nothing Then
                Me.TxtDistance = htmlDist.innerText
            'Google image code to go here after map page loads?
            End If
        End If
    (Next Case)
```

Comment: So the issue is how to export the map displayed in browser window to a jpg file? I have read that saving the image and using it outside of a Google service is against the terms of service with the API. If the AA website is serving map through Google API, might be in violation to save image. Not finding any code that will accomplish this. Windows SnippingTool or similar may be only recourse.

Comment: I found PHP code but it directly references Google API. No idea if can be done with VBA. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9358684/how-do-i-save-the-google-image-map-api-picture-to-my-server. Since you do not post HTML code, probably should not have that tag.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I must admit I began to think it was difficult or in violation when I couldn't find much information. I agree, I dont think it can be extracted easily into vba because it is the result of a 3rd party operation. I had thought about snipping too but as that was a less appealing option I put that thought to one side in favour of putting out this question. I will explore more but in the meantime I would welcome further opinions..